# Custom UINavigationBar - Animating Intrinsic Height Changes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar, intrinsic-content-size

In this particular scenario, I'm actually very confused. I have subclassed UINavigationBar, noted Apple's outdated sample code, realized that sizeToFit is never called and overrode `intrinsicContentSize` and `layoutSubviews` to calculate the necessary height. Everything works well when it comes to calculating the height based on a custom view I provide (I use `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` for calculating the height dynamically based on a custom content view/titleView).

The odd part is, when I attempt to animate any changes, I can animate changes in the custom `titleView`, but when reloading the intrinsicContentSize via `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`, the view frame changes do not animate. It snaps.

Sample code:

```
let delta = destinationTextFieldContainerView.frame.minX - originTextFieldContainerView.frame.minX + originTextFieldContainerView.frame.height
textContainersSeparatorConstraint.constant = -delta
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    self.customContainerNavigationBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    self.customContainerNavigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (_) in
        self.customContainerNavigationBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

The one constraint value change will animate, but unfortunately (because navBars don't rely on auto layout) it seems there's a problem updating the frame. I've attempted updating the frame directly before invalidating the intrinsic size with no success. I've also tried a height constraint, listing it in key frame animations with different timing offsets, invalidating the layout at different points in time, all to no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Resizing code can be found here:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    var navigationBarSize = super.intrinsicContentSize()
    navigationBarSize.width = superview?.frame.width ?? 0

    guard let  titleView = navigationItem?.titleView else {
        return navigationBarSize
    }
    let fittingSize = CGSize(width: navigationBarSize.width, height: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize.height)
    let titleViewSize = titleView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(fittingSize)

    navigationBarSize.height = max(titleViewSize.height, 44)

    navigationBarSize.width = UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
    return navigationBarSize
}


override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    guard let navigationItem = navigationItem, titleView = navigationItem.titleView else {
        return
    }
    var navigationBarSize = bounds.size
    navigationBarSize.width = superview?.frame.width ?? 0

    var fittingSize = CGSize(width: navigationBarSize.width, height: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize.height)

    if let leftBarButtonItem = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, leftButtonCustomView = leftBarButtonItem.customView {
        fittingSize.width -= leftButtonCustomView.frame.width + leftButtonCustomView.frame.origin.x + 22
    }

    let titleViewSize = titleView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(fittingSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)

    titleView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: titleView.frame.origin.x, y: 0), size: titleViewSize)
    titleView.setNeedsLayout()
    titleView.layoutIfNeeded()

    if let leftBarButtonItem = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, leftButtonCustomView = leftBarButtonItem.customView {
        var customViewFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: navigationBarSize)

        let customViewSize = leftButtonCustomView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(customViewFrame.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)
        customViewFrame.size = customViewSize
        leftButtonCustomView.frame = customViewFrame
        leftButtonCustomView.setNeedsLayout()
        leftButtonCustomView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

}
```